# After Modal Dismissal, keyboard displays the wrong color - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uikit

I have a question in regards to the color of the keyboard after a modal is dismissed. Basically, the flow goes like this...

- I press a toolbar button on a keyboard that brings up a modal view controller.
- That modal view controller dismisses itself and then calls a method on the presenting view controller that makes a text field first responder.

Here are some photos

---

Weirdly colored keyboard
[image]

---

Normal keyboard
[image]

---

In case it helps, I can get from the weirdly colored keyboard to the normal keyboard by pressing the shift key.

Comment: I'd say create a sample project and see what the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce it is. Then submit a radar to Apple.

Comment: Do you have any third party keyboards installed?

Comment: @DanielLeonard no, I do not

Comment: I am also assuming you don't have any keyboard handling code either.

Comment: @DanielLeonard that is correct

Comment: Then it probably is a system level error nothing you can do besides file a radar.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this happen when I inadvertently tried to make my input field first responder twice and also when I let the system resign and re-establish  first responder around my modal

I fixed the problem by manually resigning first responder before my modal was presented, and then manually becoming first responder again after my modal was dismissed.

You might just try manually resigning first responder before you present your modal.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the good tips +1. I'm sure that it will help somebody. Unfortunately, I am not going to be able to accept this answer because I changed the app to make it work differently and will not be able to reproduce this error to test out your solution.